# Regular Expression with variables for minimum length and number of non alphanumeric chars

Tags: c#

I am looking for a regular expression that will check for a min length and also min number of non alpha numeric chars.  where X is min length and Y is number of non alphanumeric
I will check for 0 on Y and exclude that portion if needed. 
^(?=.{X,}$)(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z].{Y})
this only works if the non alpha numeric are at the end.

justin%%, &&justin, ^`justin, and ju$t!n should all be valid, however justin#, and ju##t should not if X=6 and Y = 2
I have also tried this 
^((?=.{6,})(?=.*[^\dA-z]+.*[^\dA-z]+.*))$

Comment: There is no way for a regular expression to specify a number of non-consecutive matches.

Comment: Can you give some examples of inputs and desired outputs?

Comment: if X=6 and Y=2; justin should not be valid but ju$t!n should, also &&just, or just** should work as well